# How to change the value of array field in firebase flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array containing list of image URL in firestore. I want to delete the specific image of certain index when user clicks the delete button. This is how my firebase image array looks like [image: firebase]  Here's what i've tried

```
                                                 FirebaseFirestore
                                                            .instance
                                                            .collection(
                                                                'adsPost')
                                                            .doc(widget.id)
                                                            .update({
                                                          '${images[_current]}':
                                                              ''
                                                        }).whenComplete(() {
                                                          print(
                                                              'image removed from firestore');
                                                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, to remove it from the list in your app, and then update your firebase document with the new modified listed after the image was deleted.:

```
.update({"images": images.remove(images[_current])});
```

Or delete it from Firebase:

```
.update({"images": FieldValue.arrayRemove([images[_current]])})
```